# share datastore python between modules in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, module, google-cloud-datastore, gae-module

Im studying about GAE, Im trying to build a app with 2 module: default module and count module. Count module increaces value of Count object in datastore by 1 every min. default module access Count object and show its current value.

```
I setup default module as index.py in root directory.
 Count object in Global.py in /global/
 Count-module as count.py in /count/
```

I can access Count object form index.py through:

```
import sys
   sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "global"))
   from Global import Count
```

But I cannot access Count object from count.py in count-module:

```
 sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 
                                            "..",
                                            "global")
                   )
   from Global import Count
```

--> ImportError: No module named Global
Someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need folders, but if you do use empty `__init__.py` inside of each to make them python modules. Your project structure can be:

```
index.py
count.py
global.py
```

Then you will be able to import files from each module without changing `sys.path`. If you want folders then read this answer [What is __init__.py for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for).

**Upd.** By the way, use `global` for module name is bad idea. It is reserved word.